# Select no option

Tags: option

Tenho uma tela de contas a pagar, e quando eu vou editar os dados, no campo option está aparecendo a nome do fornecedor (**Liquigas**), até ai tudo certo.
Mas quando eu clico na lista, está aparecendo duas vezes o nome do fornecedor.
O que eu possa está fazendo de errado?

```
                <div class="form-group col-md-10">
                <label>Fornecedor</label>

                <select class="form-control form-control-sm" name="cod_for">
                    <?php

                    $sql_nome_for = "SELECT nome FROM cad_for WHERE id = '$cod_fornecedor'";
                    $sql_nome_for = $pdo->query($sql_nome_for);
                    $dado_for = $sql_nome_for->fetch();
                    ?>

                    <option><?php echo utf8_encode($dado_for['nome']); ?></option>
                    <?php   
                    $sql_for = "SELECT id, nome FROM cad_for WHERE del <> '1' ORDER BY nome";

                    $sql_for = $pdo->query($sql_for);

                    If($sql_for->rowCount()>0){

                        foreach($sql_for as $fornecedor):
                            ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $dado['id_cad_for']; ?>" ><?php echo utf8_encode($fornecedor['nome']); ?></option>
                        <?php 
                        endforeach;
                    }
                    ?>
                </select>
            </div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: San, coloquei dentro do laço, mas agora duplicou o nome.

Comment: Cloque uma condição na sua query para não retornar o nome da primeira option que fica antes do laço, algo como: `$sql_for = "SELECT id, nome FROM cad_for WHERE del <> '1' and nome <> '".$dado_for['nome']."' ORDER BY nome";`

Comment: Mas também coloque um `value` naquela option fora do laço, senão quando vc salvar vai ir vazio. Algo como: `<option value="<?php echo $cod_fornecedor; ?>"><?php echo utf8_encode($dado_for['nome']); ?></option>`

Comment: option funcionou, mas o value não está não esta funcionando, é possível o fonte dessa tela pra você San?

Comment: O value dentro do laço?

Comment: Sim, dentro do laço

Comment: Como eu faço pra deixa o código dessa tela aqui no fórum?

Comment: Coloquei todo o código.

Comment: Cara, dentro do laço vc coloca como value o `$fornecedor['id']`

Comment: Vc tá pegando nome e id do banco, certo? O id é o value e o nome o texto das option. Nem deveria editar a pergunta.

Comment: A option dentro do laço deve ficar assim: `<option value="<?php echo $fornecedor['id']; ?>" ><?php echo utf8_encode($fornecedor['nome']); ?></option>`

Comment: Não funcionou San, desculpe amigo, tua vontade é grande em me ajudar, mas vou estudar melhor o código, talvez faça um teste só com esse option, só pra ver onde estou errando, muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Tranquilo. Veja se a resposta abaixo ajuda, ou comente lá. Abs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu problema é que você está pegando os `<option>` de 2 lugares:

```
                $sql_nome_for = "SELECT nome FROM cad_for WHERE id = '$cod_fornecedor'";
                $sql_nome_for = $pdo->query($sql_nome_for);
                $dado_for = $sql_nome_for->fetch();
                ?>

                <option><?php echo utf8_encode($dado_for['nome']); ?></option>
```

E depois

```
                $sql_for = "SELECT id, nome FROM cad_for WHERE del <> '1' ORDER BY nome";

                $sql_for = $pdo->query($sql_for);

                If($sql_for->rowCount()>0){

                    foreach($sql_for as $fornecedor):
                        ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $dado['id_cad_for']; ?>" ><?php echo utf8_encode($fornecedor['nome']); ?></option>
```

A solução mais "direta" provavelmente é:

1. eliminar o `option` do primeiro `SELECT` (consultar os dados, mas nao jogar no HTML);

   <strike>`<option><?php echo utf8_encode($dado_for['nome']); ?></option>`</strike>
2. habilitar o atributo `selected` no segundo `option`:

   ```
   <option value="<?php
      echo $dado['id_cad_for'].($fornecedor['nome']==$dado_for['nome']?' selected':'');
   ?>"><?php echo utf8_encode($fornecedor['nome']); ?></option>
   ```

(quebrei em linhas só pra facilitar a leitura)

Se por algum motivo acontecer do segundo `select` não trazer o nome desejado, ou você preferir que o nome selecionado seja sempre o primeiro, pode fazer diferente:

1. mantém o `option` do primeiro `SELECT`;

   `<option><?php echo utf8_encode($dado_for['nome']); ?></option>`
2. põe um `if` no segundo `option` para não mostrar nome repetido:

   ```
   if ($fornecedor['nome']!=$dado_for['nome']) echo '<option value="'.
      $dado['id_cad_for'].'">'.utf8_encode($fornecedor['nome']).'</option>';
   ```

Aproveitando, seria bom corrigir ou o DB ou a página para eliminar o `utf8_encode`, que é uma função que só faz sentido para compatibilizar dados vindo de terceiros.

Comment: Carregou o option, porém não está alterando o código do fornecedor.